# Unable to read json file with pyspark in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm using **pyspark** to create a **dataframe** from a JSON file.

The structure of the JSON file is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "Volcano Name": "Abu",
    "Country": "Japan",
    "Region": "Honshu-Japan",
    "Location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        131.6,
        34.5
      ]
    },
    "Elevation": 571,
    "Type": "Shield volcano",
    "Status": "Holocene",
    "Last Known Eruption": "Unknown",
    "id": "4cb67ab0-ba1a-0e8a-8dfc-d48472fd5766"
  },
  {
    "Volcano Name": "Acamarachi",
    "Country": "Chile",
    "Region": "Chile-N",
    "Location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -67.62,
        -23.3
}]
```

I will read in the file using the following line of code:

```
myjson = spark.read.json("/FileStore/tables/sample.json")
```

However, I keep on getting the following error message:

> Spark Jobs
>   myjson:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
>   _corrupt_record:string

Can someone let me know what I might doing wrong?

Is the problem with the structure of the json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your JSON is multiple line Json that why issue is, to fix this below is code snippet,

```
myjson = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
         .json("/FileStore/tables/sample.json")
```

Hope this will solve issue.

Comment: Ajay, thanks for reaching out. I added your command and it appeared to work, however I now have the problem of duplicate columns. Getting the error: ```Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema: `country`;``` Is there a way to for the dataframe to still be created even with the duplicate column? If not, do you know the code the code to remove the duplicate column

Comment: just wanted to point out that there aren't any duplicate columns. So I don't know why its saying ```Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema: `country`;```

Comment: yeah, there is no duplicate column in your data, not sure why its saying like that

Comment: the full json file can be found here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-sample-data/blob/master/SampleData/VolcanoData.json

Comment: ok mate, I can assure you that there aren't any duplicates, so this is weird....

Comment: Yep, got it let me try something

Comment: Hey man, for me its working correctly now. What I found is your json is not correct when parsing it using spark. After correcting json able to parse json correctly without error.

Comment: [
  {
    "Volcano Name": "Abu",
    "Country": "Japan",
    "Region": "Honshu-Japan",
    "Location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        131.6,
        34.5
      ]
    },
    "Elevation": 571,
    "Type": "Shield volcano",
    "Status": "Holocene",
    "Last Known Eruption": "Unknown",
    "id": "4cb67ab0-ba1a-0e8a-8dfc-d48472fd5766"
  },
  {
    "Volcano Name": "Acamarachi",
    "Country": "Chile",
    "Region": "Chile-N",
    "Location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -67.62,
        -23.3
      ]
     }
   }
]

Comment: Hey,  how did you get the json all on one line like that?

Comment: Did copy and paste the json from the link? Or did you just use the VolcanaData.json directly?

Comment: Whatever json in question, I have copied that.

Comment: Ajay, how is that you're copied code above appears on a single line?

Comment: may be after pasting it, it is appearing in one line but I am having it here in mult line only, but are able to solve the issue?

Comment: Just fyi, I have processed multi line json only and thing I have corrected while doing is JSON input where some of parenthesis is missing.

Comment: I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm entering the code: ```myson = spark.read.option("multiLine", True).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("/FileStore/tables/VolcanoData.json")``` but I'm getting the error ```Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema: `country`;```

Comment: This might be issue with Json  as it is not correct, some parenthesis might be missing in Json. Try some online json validator tools for same and I am sure problem with that only.

Comment: Nop, its running fine for me after correcting json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204814/discussion-between-carltonp-and-ajay-sk).